# Defining a workflow for importing the RNA-seq count data

Tags: r

i am getting starting with R and i read some basics and syntax to get me started with it,
now i using miodin to define a project and a case-control study design.

```
library(miodin)
mp <- MiodinProject(name = "MyProject", author = "Myself", path ="." )
mshow(mp)
```

I have a file named "randseq"in my computer hard-disk which look like this.

> ID    LineA_1 LineA_2 LineA_3 LineA_4 LineA_5 LineB_1 LineB_2 LineB_3 LineB_4 LineB_5 LineB_6 LineB_7 LineB_8 LineB_9
>
> ENSG00000000003   23  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   3   3   0
>
> ENSG00000000005   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>
> ENSG00000000419   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0

Now i want to define a workflow for importing the RNA-seq count data of that file which is in a folder named analysis_with_r, using the study design. Execute the workflow and export the dataset to the project folder. Below is my code for it

```
mw <- MiodinWorkflow(name = 'MyProject')
mw <- mw + downloadRepositoryData(
    name = 'RNA downloader',
    accession = 'randseq',
    repository = '/Users/aarf/Desktop/analysis_with_r/randseq.txt',
    path = 'data',
    type = 'processed'
    )
mw <- insert(mw,mp)
mshow(mw)

mw <- execute(mw)
saveDataFile(mp)
export(mp, 'dataset', 'randseq')
```

After running this code i get this error

> [INFO] Module terminated with the following error   [ERROR] Unknown
> repository/Users/aarf/Desktop/analysis_with_r/randseq.txt
> [INFO] 1 modules were not executed [STATUS] Execution finished

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I think `downloadRepositorData()` expects an online repository and only accepts `repository = "ArrayExpress"`.

Comment: So what should i use instead of downloadRepository()? Can you help me here?